# How to remove check from checkbox when input element is hidden?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a checkbox that reveals additional options when checked, via the function below. The trouble is that if the revealed checkboxes are selected, they remain selected even after being hidden. How can I best bind the deselecting of checkboxes with the same function as them being hidden?

This is one of many similar hide-unhide groupings. Any help is appreciated! Thank you everyone

*Please note that I am doing this within a system where I can't add or change any HTML IDs or classes, which is why there is a big pile of selected items.*

```
$("input[id='form_0009_fld_5-0']").click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("input[name='form_0009_fld_6-0'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-0'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-1'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-1'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-2'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-2'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-3'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-3'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-4'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-4'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-5'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-5'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-6'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-6']").closest('.formField').show();
    } else {
        $("input[name='form_0009_fld_6-0'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-0'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-1'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-1'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-2'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-2'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-3'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-3'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-4'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-4'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-5'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-5'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-6'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-6']").closest('.formField').hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't a better way to fix this be to include an "isHidden" check in your code, rather than modifying whether or not something is checked?  This would keep the user's selection if they were to make the checkbox visible again.

Comment: Also, can you give us a JSFiddle demonstrating this problem?

Comment: You can modify any DOM element with jquery, so you still can add class to inputs your are targetting, better than using unreadable selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery allows you to chain functions so you can add on to the end of the `hide`.

For example:

```
$('longselector').closest('.formField').hide().attr("checked", false);
```

And with the rest of your code.

```
$("input[id='form_0009_fld_5-0']").click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("input[name='form_0009_fld_6-0'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-0'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-1'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-1'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-2'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-2'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-3'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-3'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-4'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-4'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-5'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-5'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-6'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-6']").closest('.formField').show();
    } else {
        $("input[name='form_0009_fld_6-0'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-0'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-1'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-1'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-2'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-2'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-3'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-3'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-4'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-4'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-5'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-5'],input[name='form_0009_fld_6-6'],label[for='form_0009_fld_6-6']").closest('.formField').hide().attr("checked", false);
        }
});
```

Comment: Oh man, this was driving me nuts. I figured out it was the order of my chain that I had to fix (I assume that putting the unchecking attr() at the end was applying it to the .closest() maybe?). The following works:    `$("selectors").prop("checked", false).closest('.formField').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

The attributes selector can match "starts with", "ends with", and a lot of other options, so there's no need to type in a bunch of similar selectors like that?

To set the checkboxes to "unchecked", you'd use `prop('checked', false)` if the checkbox that was initially toggled is not checked etc, and using the `change` event is probably better than a `click` event :

```
$("input[id^='form_0009_fld_5']").on('change', function() {
    var elems = $('input[name^="form_0009_fld_6"]'),
        state = this.checked;

    elems.closest('.formField').toggle(state);

    if (!state) elems.prop('checked', false);
});
```